# I need a server that I can access via API and it will execute the schedule

Tags: telegram-bot

I am making a telegram bot that publishes messages to telegram via TelegramBotsApi. I need that the admin who publishes the message can postpone it. I can't find the "scheduled" parameter in the "sendMessage" request, and I can't use either sleep or scheduled in the code, because my bot is made on a constructor.

Bottom line question - maybe you know some server that can receive post data via http request from the bot administrator and schedule messages to post pending messages? My builder knows how to send http requests and send webhook.

Or - how can I schedule pending messages via http request parameter, similar to how it is realized in telegram client itself?

If you have any other options to solve my problem - please write me. Also, no negativity, please, I am new to this task

Thank you!

I scrolled through 10+ pages on google looking for a solution and came across this - https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendScheduledMessages

But I don't think it will work

Comment: A quick google search lead me to [this](https://core.telegram.org/api/scheduled-messages#:~:text=To%20schedule%20a%20message%2C%20simply,sent%20at%20the%20specified%20time.) which documents how to use scheduled messages. I guess this answers your question?

Comment: I attached a link to that page in my question, and it might work - but not for me, I can't use the code in my bot since I'm doing it on a constructor, at most - JS on ES5

Comment: The page I linked is different from what you've posted. However, what do you mean by "I can't use the code in my bot since I'm doing it on a constructor"? Which library are you using, since there are plenty JS libraries for interacting with Telegram's Bot API. Or are you interacting with the plain HTTP API by encoding the requests yourself? Could you perhaps provide the relevant excerpt from your code?

Comment: I'm making a bot in the Telegram bot builder. I don't know what library is used to execute the js code, I guess it is missing